# Node.js Debug Gif

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, debugging, gif

Trying to work on some code that has no issues on other computers. This problem seems to be specific to my laptop and no other computers. Even a "hello world" app only returns a debug gif.

```
repository folder> node app.js 
Express Server Listening on port 3000
GET / 200 1000.00 ms - -
```

This is the code delivered to the browser instead of my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.1" name="viewport">

    <title>127.0.0.1 (1×1)</title>
    <style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0px;">
    <img src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/" style="-webkit-user-select: none">
</body>
</html>
```

Troubleshooting included:

- Ran cmd as admin
- Re-installing Node.js
- Deleted temp npm & npm cache folders in appdata/roaming

No error on the development tools in chrome or Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Kaspersky blocks 127.0.0.1 activity. Add Web Anti-Virus Exclusions Trusted URLS & Safe Surf fixes this issue.

Simply disabling the Antivirus didn't fix the issue for me. The Exclusions are a necessity